# Android Emulator boots up with flashy 'Android' but the application never starts up and I wont see any Home Screen

Tags: android, android-emulator

Android Emulator  boots up with flashy 'Android' but the application never starts up and I wont see any Home Screen even after waiting for 30 min. I use PC of RAM 2 GB still I am unable to see the hOme screen on Emullator.. The Console is as

```
[2012-02-26 17:36:52 - SDK Manager] Created AVD 'GingerBread2.3.3' based on Android             2.3.3, ARM (armeabi) processor,
[2012-02-26 17:36:52 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2012-02-26 17:36:52 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=160
[2012-02-26 17:36:52 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=24
[2012-02-26 17:36:52 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=256
[2012-02-26 17:37:11 - test_ball_handler] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-02-26 17:37:11 - test_ball_handler] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to   be launched...
[2012-02-26 17:42:00 - test_ball_handler] ------------------------------
[2012-02-26 17:42:00 - test_ball_handler] Android Launch!
[2012-02-26 17:42:00 - test_ball_handler] adb is running normally.
[2012-02-26 17:42:00 - test_ball_handler] Performing com.eg.a.Test_ball_handlerActivity activity launch
[2012-02-26 17:42:00 - test_ball_handler] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'GingerBread2.3.3'
[2012-02-26 17:42:00 - test_ball_handler] Uploading test_ball_handler.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-02-26 17:42:01 - test_ball_handler] Installing test_ball_handler.apk...
[2012-02-26 17:44:15 - test_ball_handler] Failed to install test_ball_handler.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-02-26 17:44:15 - test_ball_handler] (null)
[2012-02-26 17:44:15 - test_ball_handler] Launch canceled!
[2012-02-26 17:47:56 - test_ball_handler] ------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the ADB connection timeout. 
I think it defaults that to 5000ms and I changed mine to 10000ms to get rid of that problem. If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through Window -> Preferences and then it is in DDMS under Android.

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon for an AVD to be born (or become) corrupt/misbehaving. The solution for that is to make a new AVD (with same settings) and delete the corrupt/misbehaving one.

Another possible problem is AVDs can eat up a lot of your CPU, so if your system is already in struggle-town, chances of AVD booting and running nicely is slim.